# Raspberry PI SMb1 Gateway for streaming 16 bit music

Tags: networking

I'll start by saying i'm a Pi complete noob - Windows or Linux server I do understand well.

Sonos S1 devices will only use SMBv1 protocol to access my mediaserver (NAS). I want to switch off SMBv1 on my NAS for the obvious security reasons (it is also my fileserver).

So the plan is setup a Pi to act as a gateway using SMBv1 to stream to the Sonos speakers, and to mount the music folder from my NAS using SMB/NFS or similar. I can then remove SMBv1 from the NAS.

TO answer some questions people may think of:

- I can configure the Sonos S1 to "talk" specifically to the Pi
- Sonos S1 doesn't fully support UPNP/DLNA
- Sonos S1 will never be able to support SMBv2

The system will be run headless.

1. I understand the the PI has a linux like O/S upon which I can install Samba - please correct me if i'm wrong/there is a better option for the O/S.
2. The Pi needs to support a maximum of two 16 bit music streams simultaneously. Which Pi model should I use - i'd like the cheapest possible option.

Hopefully the above has sufficient info and makes sense!

Thanks in advance
Dave

Comment: `the PI has a linux like O/S` - yes, have you heard of Debian? or Ubuntu? these are just 2 of the "linux like O/S" you can install on the pi - with your "understand well" Linux knowledge, you should have no issues. Go for the 3B+

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thx Jaromanada - I run my NAS on Ubuntu so that will be a breeze